# Question about Euler's equation for rigid bodies

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, cross-product

I wished to understand a particular case of Euler's equation applied in the following cylindrical body:

[image]

where $I_{1,2,3}$ are the moments of inertia. By symmetry, $I_1=I_2=I_T$.

Here I consider that no external forces are applied to the cylinder. Stating the equations by their components, we have that:

$$I_1\dot{\omega}_1-(I_2-I_3)\omega_2\omega_3=0$$
$$I_2\dot{\omega}_2-(I_3-I_1)\omega_3\omega_1=0$$
$$I_3\dot{\omega}_3-(I_1-I_2)\omega_1\omega_2=0$$

where $\omega_i$ is the rotation speed on axis $\hat{b}_i$.

My question is the following: Considering that initially the cylinder spins with speed $\omega_3$, suddenly it starts to move around axis $\hat{b}_1$ and/or $\hat{b}_2$, that is, $\omega_1$ and/or $\omega_2$ suddenly are different than zero. According to the third equation, $\omega_3$ should remain constant after that, because $I_1-I_2=0$. But I imagine that to conserve its momentum, as the cylinder is rotated to a "laid" position, it would keep spinning around $\hat{b}_3$, but with a different velocity because $I_3\neq I_T$.

Am I interpreting this equation wrong?

Comment: This subject is treated in V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics*. In short: The Euler equation holds in the so called body coordinates. Arnold writes it as $\dot{\mathbf{M}}=[\mathbf{M},\boldsymbol{\Omega}]$ (cross product of angular momentum and angular velocity). When these two are parallel then $\mathbf{M}$ is constant which means that the body rotates stably around  its main principal axis.

Comment: @KurtG. The example in the book is very on point, thank you, but there's one difference: there is only the $\omega_3$ component there, and no rotation around the other axes. I don't know if my example makes sense, but it considers that $\omega_1$ or $\omega_2$ is different than 0

Comment: In Arnold section 29 of chapter 6 you find your system of equations where the author writes $\Omega_1,\Omega_2,\Omega_3$ instead of $\omega_1,\omega_2,\omega_3$ to signify that these angular velocities are (again) in ***body*** coordinates. This system of equations is equivalent to the one I mentioned in the last comment. In short: your case is fully covered and your question can be answered by patiently studying Arnold's book. I did that once and found it was one of the best exercises I had done in a long time.

Comment: I believe that the confusion comes from thinking that the system of equations linking the moments of inertia $I_i$ to angular velocities holds in *space* coordinates but it does not. Arnold writes lower case letters for quantities in space coordinates. Then, when there is no external torque: $\dot{\mathbf{m}}=0$ which means in your case (picture): when the body initially rotates around $\mathbf{b}_3$ this will not change.

Comment: Shoudn't the body velocity in relation to the body coordinates always be 0 by definition?

Since we are here, I wanted to add another question about rotational dynamics, regarding this explanation about the intermediate axis theorem: https://youtu.be/1VPfZ_XzisU?t=404

In this intuitive explanation, why doesn't the same effect happen when the disk is rotated 90°, that is, if we switched the big and small masses? Is this explanation flawed?

Thank you in advance for the answers

Comment: By what definition? Certainly not by Arnold's who is an ultimative authority. Have you read the relevant chapter in his book? [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647024/304394).

Comment: @ArthurFagundes - The body velocity is not calculated in the body frame; that would give $0$. It is calculated in the inertial frame, and then simply rotated into the body frame (i.e. expressed in terms of the rotating basis vectors $b_1,b_2,b_3$).